# Переменные-указатели и алгоритмы упорядочивания массивов

Tags: c++

> Разработать схему алгоритма и написать программу, которая создает
>   динамический массив с количеством элементов по выбору пользователя,
>   заполняет его через консоль или неупорядоченными значениями из
>   программы и выполняет их сортировка по методу вставки. Тип данных
>   массива unsigned int. Принцип сортировки увеличение (рост).

Все что я смог так это сделать заполнение массива и то не уверен что правильно.

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>
#include<vector>

using namespace std; 

void RandomShuffle(int *pA, int r, int x, int n)
{
    const int VECTOR_SIZE = r ; 

    typedef vector<int> IntVector ;
    typedef IntVector::iterator IntVectorIt ;
    IntVector Numbers(VECTOR_SIZE) ;
    IntVectorIt start, end, it ;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) 
    {
        Numbers[i] = x;
        x = x + n;
    }

    start = Numbers.begin();
    end = Numbers.end();

    random_shuffle(start, end);

    for(it = start; it != end; it++)
        *(pA++)=*it;
}
```

Comment: 1. Разработать схему алгоритма. Есть?
2. Создавать динамический массив с кол-вом элементов... Есть?
И так далее.
В чем вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Создание:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> v(n);
```

Заполнение из "терминала":

```
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<unsigned int>(std::cin), n, std::back_inserter(v));
```

Стандартная сортировка:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Если самому надо реализовать сортировку, то загуглить не составляет труда:

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сортировка_вставками#Псевдокод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8#%D0%9F%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)